# Choropleth Map Using Python

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I have created a choropleth map using python, which shows confirmed cases for each state based on latitude and longitude. However, I am unable to input the data that I want from my dataset.

Here is my code that I tried:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("COVID19-DATA-01-ONLYSTATES.csv")

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations = df["AdminRegion1"],
    z = df["Confirmed"],
    locationmode = 'USA-states', # set of locations match entries in `locations`
    colorscale = 'Reds',

))

fig.update_layout(
    geo_scope='usa', 
)

fig.show()
```

Here is a picture of my dataset.
[image]

Comment: First, Group by state and sum on confirmed column. Second, add state code column in dataframe and use it as locations instead of "AdminRegion1". These two changes would make your work way easy.

Comment: Hey sir, thank you for the suggestion. Could you possibly explain it a bit more? I apologize I am very new to programming so it is hard to understand all of this.

Comment: Sure. Could you please add some sample data in question.

Comment: Hi, the only way I could get the data was to attach the link. Is there anyway else you would like it?

Comment: Thanks. Link helped me but for next time please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) .

Comment: Check answer and add comment if it is not helpful otherwise consider to accept

Comment: Definitely accepted! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is for all countries as provided data suggests and also you didn't mention about it.
If you want for specific country, add STATE_CODE in dataframe.(right now, STATE_CODE is missing) [check](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#united-states-choropleth-map)

You need some data preprocessing before plotting raw data into map.

**Data Preprocessing:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.read_csv("Bing-COVID19-Data.csv")

selected_columns = ["ID", "Country_Region", "ISO3", "Updated", "Confirmed", "Deaths", "Recovered"] # select columns for plot
sdf = df[selected_columns] 
sdf = sdf[sdf.ISO3.notnull()] # remove null from ISO3, like worldwide wont have any ISO code etc
sdf["Updated"] = pd.to_datetime(sdf.Updated) # Convert Updated column type from str to datetime

sdf = (sdf
       .loc[sdf.groupby('ISO3').Updated.idxmax()] # select only latest date for each contry as you have cumalative sum  
       .reset_index(drop=True)
       .sort_values(["Country_Region"])
      )
```

**Plot:**

```
sdf = sdf.astype(str) # convert columns type to styr to make hover data in plot

sdf["hover_data"] = sdf['Country_Region'] + '<br>' + \
    'Updated: ' + sdf['Updated'] + '<br>' + \
    'Confirmed: ' + sdf['Confirmed'] + '<br>' + \
    'Deaths: ' + sdf['Deaths'] + '<br>' + 'Recovered: ' + sdf['Recovered']

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations = sdf['ISO3'],
    z = sdf['Confirmed'],
    text = sdf['hover_data'],
    colorscale = 'Reds',
    autocolorscale=False,
    marker_line_color='darkgray',
    marker_line_width=0.5,
    colorbar_title = 'Confirmed Cases',
))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='COVID-19 Cases',
    geo=dict(
        showframe=False,
        showcoastlines=False    )
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, so I did forget to mention it was countries, but what I did was I filtered it to only the United States, using pandas.